# Facebook Score API - get all scores for my app / game

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I'm running into trouble...question is, on Facebook, how do I return a list of all the scores that were posted against my app / game?

Here's my code:

```
function lbInit() {
            FB.api('/' + globalFBObj.appID + '/scores', 'get', function(response) {
                console.log("Getting scores...");
                console.log(response);

                //pass array into Lboard() and construct the leaderboard
                console.log("Creating the Leaderboard...");
                Lboard(response.data); 
            });
        }
```

But the only thing that returns is the current user's posted score...

I am requesting the following permissions: 
   scope: 'email,publish_actions,user_games_activity,friends_games_activity'

Comment: Do the friends of your current user who used your app and have posted scores have the sharing of app activity with apps used by friends enabled in their privacy settings?

Comment: I realized that the code was working -- I just didn't have any friends tied to the app, so it only showed my scores